# Design Cache Mechanism (Redis)

Tags: caching, redis

I want to design my Caching mechanism which involves least network calls.

I've a remote redis server, and my keys are designed as such.

**Parent: Details**

```
Group1: {
name: XYZ,
phone: 1234,
age: 12
}
```

**Child: Group1**

```
ABC: Group1
DEF: Group1
```

So, the input provided is child, ie `ABC` and I've to return `Group details`. Now, when I query my cache, I first GET the `GroupID` given the `child`, and then GET the `group details`. This involves 2 network calls to the remote server. Can I change my cache design to support only 1 network call, without duplication of data.

Is there any way where I can set `child` as a key in `group details` and value as the `list of child` and simulataneously GET the group details in O(1) time given the child?

Comment: Have you looked at using lua scripts to perform both operations server side?